# Using Ninject to Setup Nhibernate with two databases

Tags: nhibernate, ninject

I am trying to set up my application so that Audit information is saved on a spearate database.  I have been able to set-up and configure NHibernate to use one database using Ninject, but not to my second database.

This is what I have tried:

```
public class NHibernateModule : NinjectModule
{   
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionFactory>()
            .ToMethod(c => NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory())
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISessionFactory>()
            .ToMethod(c => NHibernateHelper.CreateLoggingSessionFactory())
            .WhenInjectedInto<BaseLoggingModel>()
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());


    }
}

public static class NHibernateHelper
{
    public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        return cfg.Configure().SetProperty("connection.connection_string_name", "ApplicationServices").BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    public static ISessionFactory CreateLoggingSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        return cfg.Configure().SetProperty("connection.connection_string_name", "AuditingServices").BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Unfortunatley, only the CreateSessionFactory() method is ever called and I can't get a Session to my audit databse.

Any help would be greatly appreceiated

Answer (score 1):

The condition must be on the session

```
    Bind<ISessionFactory>()
        .ToMethod(c => NHibernateHelper.CreateSessionFactory())
        .Named("Default")
        .InSingletonScope();

    Bind<ISessionFactory>()
        .ToMethod(c => NHibernateHelper.CreateLoggingSessionFactory())
        .Named("Logging")
        .InSingletonScope();

    Bind<ISession>()
        .ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("Default").OpenSession());
    Bind<ISession>()
        .ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("Logging").OpenSession())
        .WhenInjectedInto<BaseLoggingModel>();
```

The condition might also be wrong. BaseLoggingModel sounds as if you derive various classes. So you have to use your own When condition checking if the class is derived from BaseLoggingModel instead of WhenInjectedInto

Comment: I could not get this to work. I have a similar problem and posted a question here: I have a similar problem and posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392011/ninject-nhinbernate-with-two-or-more-databases