# Ninject + NHibernate with two or more databases

Tags: c#, nhibernate, ninject

I have declared my Ninject bindings in a NinjectModule like this:

```
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(c => SessionFactory1.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope().Named("d1");
    Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(c => SessionFactory2.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope().Named("d2");

    Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("d1").OpenSession()).Named("d1");
    Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("d2").OpenSession()).Named("d2");

    Bind(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<,>)).To(typeof(Repository<,>)).Named("d1").WithConstructorArgument("session", c => c.Kernel.Get<ISession>("d1"));
    Bind(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<,>)).To(typeof(Repository<,>)).Named("d2").WithConstructorArgument("session", c => c.Kernel.Get<ISession>("d2"));
}
```

If a run a to resolved a IReadonlyRepository I get an exception from Ninject (ActivationException: Error activating Repository{ulong, Workflow}) can anyone spot the error in my binding configuration?

```
IReadOnlyRepository repository1 = kernel.Get<Repository<UInt64, Workflow>>("d1");
```

Comment: Try to use different name for session and repository, for example "s1" and "s2" for ISessions and "r1" "r2" for IReadOnlyRepository

Answer (score 0):

Try with different name like these:

```
public override void Load() 
        { 
            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(c => SessionFactory1.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope().Named("d1"); 
            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(c => SessionFactory2.SessionFactory).InSingletonScope().Named("d2"); 

            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("d1").OpenSession()).Named("s1"); 
            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>("d2").OpenSession()).Named("s2"); 

            Bind(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<,>)).To(typeof(Repository<,>)).WithConstructorArgument("session", c => c.Kernel.Get<ISession>("s1")).Named("r1"); 
            Bind(typeof(IReadOnlyRepository<,>)).To(typeof(Repository<,>)).WithConstructorArgument("session", c => c.Kernel.Get<ISession>("s2")).Named("r2"); 
        } 

IReadOnlyRepository repository1 = kernel.Get<IReadOnlyRepository>("r1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Max Zerbini but I have tried that. It works if I only have binding to one ISessionFactory and ISession and the binding to the repository is without a name.

Comment: I'm getting an ActivationException from Ninject, either on the Repository or the ISession. I've been reading up on Ninject and suspect what I'm trying to do is not possible this way. The problem is that ISession is already known to Ninject when the Repository binding is added and WithConstructorArgument is not working as I think it does.

Comment: I was experimenting with Ninject and after spending almost a full day on this I give up. Ill try another DI framework next.